# Запуск функции по окончанию каждого календарного месяца python

Tags: python, дата, события, время

Проблема в том, что в разных месяцах разное количество дней, а функцию требуется запускать по окончании календарного месяца.
Первое, что приходит в голову, это записать словарь с названием месяца и количеством дней в нем, а затем сверяться с ним в бесконечном цикле. Но уверен есть более простые и грамотные решения задачи. В идеале без обращения к каким-либо веб сервисам.

При этом важно, чтоб запуск функции производился вовремя, даже при условии перезапуска скрипта на протяжении месяца

```
def event():
    pass
```

Comment: Встроенные модули datetime, dateutil, calendar - в них ничего подходящего не нашлось?

Comment: первое, что должно приходить на ум - использовать стандартные скедьюлеры системы

Comment: `calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]`, а для запуска каждый день либо стандартный шедулер системы, либо модуль питона `schedule`. Запускаете шедулером каждый день, проверяете, что это подходящий день.

Answer (score 1):

Рядом с исполняемым файлом лежит текстовой документ `old.txt` в котором содержится старый месяц. При условии, что месяц из файла и месяц сейчас отличаются - запускаем функцию и перезаписываем в файл информацию о текущем месяце.

Достаточно запускать проверку раз в день.

```py
import datetime

def my_func():
    print('Новый месяц!')

def check_month():
  now = datetime.datetime.now()
  month = now.month
  with open('old.txt', 'r+') as f:
    old = int(f.readline())
    if old != month:
      f.seek(0)
      f.truncate(0)
      f.write(str(month))
      my_func()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_month()
```